# Uploading Animated GIF files using Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working on a project where we're trying to allow users to upload images to their Facebook Pages.  Currently we've got Photos figured out, but, animated .GIF files transmit successfully yet show only the first frame.

When posting these same files directly to FB, they display properly.

It is my understanding that FB converts animated images to .mp4 (or another format) to treat them effectively like video.

We're discussing whether or not we should do that conversion ourselves and transmit them as videos, though they behave differently on the newsfeed.

I'm looking for assistance in what the proper API call to make is to successfully publish animated gifs.  Apologies if this is a redundant post -- there are many others but none have a definitive answer and many are years old.

The one piece of advice I've seen (but haven't gotten confirmation on) is to transmit an animated gif as a URL rather than the file itself.  I'm not fully sure of what this means.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since this was posted more then 2 years ago, i'm curious if you have found the answer to this question. I'm having the same problem and want to know the solution also. Any info is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I posted animated GIF's through the Photo Upload - Graph API endpoint. I assumed this was the correct way, because in the documentation they say GIF is supported as photo upload.

Because they GIF's uploaded via this endpoint didn't animate, I tried the Video API endpoint instead and it worked perfectly.

So, for animated GIF's to work properly, you have to use the Video API endpoint: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/video-api/guides/publishing/

Answer (score 0):

Uploading a gif as a video is the correct answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).